# array($_SESSION[''tab']) automatically adds one

Tags: php, arrays

I'm about to go crazy...
I have such a simple code:

```
$tab = array();
    $_SESSION['tab'] = $tab;
    $_SESSION['tab']['id'] = $row["userid"];
    $_SESSION['tab']['login'] = $row["login"];
```

I want to display the data like this later:
`echo $_SESSION['tab']['login'];`

The array contains such data:

```
Array ( [id] => 123456 [login] => admin ) 1
```

Why is the number one at the end? how to remove it?
$ _SESSION ['tab'] ['id'] displays the data correctly, but $ _SESSION ['tab'] ['login'] prints the data as "admin1" (with that damn ONE at the end...)

Comment: Please show us the code that outputs the data (where you see that `1`). Do you have a `echo` before a `print_r($_SESSION['tab'])` by any chance? If yes, then remove the `echo` since `print_r()` outputs the data by itself and just returns a boolean (which becomes a `1` when converted to a string by the `echo` statement)

Comment: YES!! Unfortunately I had `echo` just for fast test. Thank you so much for save time and nerves.